# Google Search Title after changing web structure

Tags: google-search, wordpress

I have a question regarding Google search results.

I modified my web structure (it's a website for an event) and now my search result titles are misleading.

Before I modified it, the google search results were like this  **: Event 2015 - MyCompany**, the event base url was **event.com**

I changed the web's structure so I could add newer events, now the 2015 Event is in **event.com/2015** while the new one, 2017 event's base url is **event.com**

I used the indexing request feature on google, added all the site's urls and it did update the search results. However it's still misleading.

Now the search result are like this  **: Event 2017 - event 2015 - MyCompany**.

I've checked the setting pages, the codes(title tags, metas), the database, there weren't anything that contain string 'event 2015'. I'm using wordpress.

Do I need to give google more time for it's to be updated?  or do I need to do something else? the site has been up for a day since its modified. I wanna make sure i've done all i could.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: At first blush, I rather suspect your title tags are too short. Your title tags should be 45-55 characters in length at least. You do not give an example of what you set your new title tag as. That would be helpful information. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Google use your main homepage title when the length of other webpages title are small.

In your main homepage(event.com) your title was `Event 2015 - MyCompany` in past, so Google will use that title everywhere when other pages title are small.

The problem is here, Google is not real time when it comes to crawling and indexing, so they still use your `Event 2015 - MyCompany`, when title length of any webpage is small. Actually what mislead here is Google still using your old homepage title when length of any webapge title are small, instead they should use new one, but the problem will not going to solve even it they assign new one as your homepage title, I mean for your event.com/2015 the title will be `Event 2015 - Event 2017 MyCompany.`

The only solution is to increase your all webpages title to  45-55 characters. Something like Event Name in your city - Year . And use your main company name in homepage only.